# SSDT registry Hoooking

Tags: windows, api

I am a new developer in kernel programming and driver concept.

I need to hook `ssdt` for protection of some keys value of registry, but I cant find any useful tutorial or simple source code for this stuff.

I found that `zwopenkey` and `zwcreatkey` should be hooked and permission of them changes to read only. 
I am looking for some examples of SSDT registry hooking.

Comment: [Does this help](http://pastebin.com/6Z2X9mJ5)?

Comment: Keep in mind that SSDT hooking is a legacy technology which will not work in 64-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: thanks, but i need a 32-bit version of win driver.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hook SSDT and You shouldn't do this. There are other possibilities to protect Your keys. One of many solutions is for example to use [registry callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).