# How to detect process name which access to designated registry like process monitor

Tags: c, windows, device-driver

[image]

How to detect process name which access to designated registry like process monitor?

Older regmon do it using SSDT Hooking ,but in windows 10, we can't hook
registry using it.[SSDT Hooking seem to be legacy technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017340/ssdt-registry-hoooking).

Are there substituites for SSDT Hooking to hook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a proper [*registry filtering driver*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/filtering-registry-calls).

> A registry filtering driver is any kernel-mode driver that filters registry calls, such as the driver component of an antivirus software package. The configuration manager, which implements the registry, allows registry filtering drivers to filter any thread's calls to registry functions.

Comment: Thank you for reply.I try to research it.